# clickable ="false" How do I use accessibility to click it

Tags: java, android, flutter

How do I click this element by using accessibility on android studio the clickable = false i've tried several method like clickButtonByContentDescription but it does not work at all.(I am not good at english)It an android app.I'm new to coding and I've been using chatgpt 4 for advice and it tell me to clickby contentdesc and getsure[target button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjdx5.png)

Comment: If you need any information just let me know. Maybe it take a while for me to reply.

Comment: what are you actually trying to do can u explain a bit more. I mean do you need a code to make it clickable?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: No. I want to automate another app using accessibility that performs clicking buttons for me and my target button clickable is set to false what can I do about it? It can be click on real device